# Antlr4 skipping a rule without error

Tags: java, antlr4

I have a very simple grammar. *antlr4* seems to be skipping the `toLabel` rule in the following grammar.

```
grammar SOSLGrammar;
options {
  language = Java;
}

main : query;

query : findClause
        toLabelClause?
        searchGroupClause?
        ;
findClause : find '{' searchClause '}';
find : Find;
searchClause : '(' searchClause ')'                     #bracketedSearch
             | searchClause AND NOT searchClause        #notSearch
             | searchClause AND searchClause            #andSearch
             | searchClause OR searchClause             #orSearch
             |terms                                     #simple
             ;

terms : term+;
term : StringLiteral|('"' reservedWordsWithOperators '"') | (TermLiteral|reservedWords);

toLabelClause : ToLabel '(' ')';

searchGroupClause : IN (email|all|phone|sidebar|name) Fields;
name : Name;
email : Email;
all : All;
phone : Phone;
sidebar : Sidebar;

reservedWordsWithOperators : reservedWords | NOT | AND | OR |IN;
reservedWords : Find|ToLabel|Name|Email|All|Phone|Sidebar;

Find : F I N D;
ToLabel :  T O L A B E L;
Fields : F I E L D S;
Name : N A M E;
All : A L L;
Phone : P H O N E;
Sidebar : S I D E B A R;
Email : E M A I L;

AND : A N D;
OR : O R;
NOT : N O T;
IN : I N;

StringLiteral :  '"' (  ~('\\'|'"') )* '"';
TermLiteral : ~('\\'|'"' | ' ' | '\t' | '}' | '{' | '\r' | '\n')+;
WS : (' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\t' | '\f' | '\b' | '\r\n' )+ -> skip;


fragment A : 'A' | 'a' ;
fragment B : 'B' | 'b' ;
fragment C : 'C' | 'c' ;
fragment D : 'D' | 'd' ;
fragment E : 'E' | 'e' ;
fragment F : 'F' | 'f' ;
fragment G : 'G' | 'g' ;
fragment H : 'H' | 'h' ;
fragment I : 'I' | 'i' ;
fragment J : 'J' | 'j' ;
fragment K : 'K' | 'k' ;
fragment L : 'L' | 'l' ;
fragment M : 'M' | 'm' ;
fragment N : 'N' | 'n' ;
fragment O : 'O' | 'o' ;
fragment P : 'P' | 'p' ;
fragment Q : 'Q' | 'q' ;
fragment R : 'R' | 'r' ;
fragment S : 'S' | 's' ;
fragment T : 'T' | 't' ;
fragment U : 'U' | 'u' ;
fragment V : 'V' | 'v' ;
fragment W : 'W' | 'w' ;
fragment X : 'X' | 'x' ;
fragment Y : 'Y' | 'y' ;
fragment Z : 'Z' | 'z' ;
```

I ran the following test:

> java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig SOSLGrammar main -gui -trace

with following line

> find {abc} toLabel()

I expect the generated tree to show `toLabel()` but it seems to be silently ignored.

What could be wrong with this grammar?

Thanks

Rahul
~

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the input `toLabel()` to produce 3 tokens:

- `toLabel`
- `(`
- `)`

In reality, since the `TermLiteral` rule allows for `(` and `)` characters to appear, the single `TermLiteral` token `toLabel()` is being produced. That token is chosen over a `ToLabel` token because it is longer.